# What Liunx video editors support keyframed speed ramping?

Tags: linux

On Mac OS, [Final Cut Pro supports speed ramping](https://support.apple.com/guide/final-cut-pro/create-variable-speed-effects-ver95783cbbc/mac). How about Linux video editors?

Kdenlive and Shotcut don't support speed ramping at all, so it has to be done [manually](https://forum.shotcut.org/t/how-to-apply-a-cinematic-speed-ramp-transition-on-shotcut-has-anyone-else-run-into-the-shown-issue/21852/). Apparently the [Olive editor doesn't support](https://www.reddit.com/r/olive/comments/hreqgd/speed_key_framing/) it either. [DaVinci Resolve supports speed ramping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7lXiPCHaHI), but it requires an NVidia GPU.